# SQL timeout on specific select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, timeout

I have a SQL query like the one below. The database tables are not indexed and unfortunately I cannot do anything about it. In the application using this query I have experienced sporadic SQL timeouts.

When such a timeout was happening I used `LinqPad` to execute the exact same query with the same parameters
and it also timed out. Although `tableA` and `tableB` were accessible and when I removed one of the output columns the query worked fine.

What can cause this behavior and what can I do about it? Thanks.

```
SELECT 
    a.ID, 
    a.NAME,
    b.VALUE 
FROM 
    tableA as a
INNER JOIN 
    tableB bb 
ON 
    bb.OWNER = a.ID
INNER JOIN 
    tableB as b 
ON 
    b.OWNER = bb.ID 
WHERE
    a.OWNER = '1234567890' 
    AND b.NAME = 'XYZ' 
ORDER BY
    b.VALUE
```

Comment: "and when I removed one of the output columns" -- doing that changes the [execution plan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan). In particular, removing `b.VALUE` can greatly simplify things since SQL Server doesn't need to bother with most of the logic accessing `b`, as long as it can prove a row from `a` would match, while removing `a.NAME` may make an existing index covering, and so on.

Comment: Your general question is "how do I troubleshoot why this query invocation is slow", which is very broad indeed. I don't think there's a SO question that gives you a good handle on that (if there is, I haven't found it), although there are plenty of resources, of course.